# R Shiny Nav Page show a weird active pane

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

Here is the reproducible good, I get the weird block next to title and "tab-pane active tab-9091-1" on the screen.

```
    library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    ui = navbarPage(
        title = "app",collapsible = TRUE, inverse = TRUE, theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
               
               list(
                   #tags$head(HTML('<link rel="icon", href="Rplot.png", type="image/png" />')),
                   
                   tags$style(HTML("
      .navbar .navbar-nav {float: left; 
                           color: red; 
                           font-size: 20px; 
                           background-color: black ; } 
      .navbar .navbar-header {float: left; } 
      .navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #red; 
                                      font-size: 38px; 
                                      background-color: #yellow ;} 

  "))),
        tabPanel("Tab1", "content1"),
        tabPanel("Tab2", "content2")
    ),
    server = function(input, output){}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    title = "app",collapsible = TRUE, inverse = TRUE,theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      .navbar .navbar-nav {float: left; 
                           color: red; 
                           font-size: 20px; 
                           background-color: black ; } 
      .navbar .navbar-header {float: left; } 
      .navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #red; 
                                      font-size: 38px; 
                                      background-color: #yellow ;} 

  "))),
    tabPanel("Tab1", "content1"),
    tabPanel("Tab2", "content2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh so it won't work with the Shiny Themes?

Comment: It works with shiny themes as well. I did not had that package installed hence I removed that part of the code.

Comment: So when I add this : theme = shinytheme("darkly"), it gives me the same error.

Comment: I just checked. I did not get any error after including the theme. I updated my answer to show the output that I get.

Comment: The space between App and Tab1 in black is also something i'm trying to avoid.